# Show/Hide content of nested divs

Tags: jquery, html

Tab 1 and Tab 2 show and hide as expected but the nested divs do not show.
How can I modify the script to show/hide the Tab 1 div/Tab 2 div and the nested divs within.

script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#content div").hide(); // Initially hide all content
        $("#vtabs li:first").attr("id", "current"); // Activate first tab
        $("#content div:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content
        $('#vtabs a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($(this).closest("li").attr("id") == "current") { //detection for current tab
                return
            }
            else {
                $("#content div").hide(); //Hide all content
                $("#vtabs li").attr("id", ""); //Reset id's
                $(this).parent().attr("id", "current"); // Activate this
                $('#' + $(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
            }
        });
    });
    (function() {
        var bsa = document.createElement('script');
        bsa.async = true;
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(bsa);
    })();​
```

html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tabs3.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">site title</div>
    <div id="vtabs">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" name="tab1">By Service</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" name="tab2">By Client</a>
                <br />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="tab1">Tab 1
            <br />
            <div>Tab 1 nested div</div>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2">Tab 2
            <br />
            <div>Tab 2 nested div</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where is the code for hiding /showing the nested divs?

Answer (score 0):

There is no where in the code that I see where you show the nested divs. 
I suggest you give the container divs a class, call it tab_contents for say. Like so

```
<div id="tab1" class="tab_contents">
```

And then change this line  `$("#content div").hide();` to  `$(".tab_contents").hide();` at both places. 
The problem is you are hiding all the divs in #content, but only fadein the container divs and not the nested divs. Only hide the container divs.